# AvalonDock: Dynamically changing LayoutAnchorablePane's CanClose property

Tags: wpf, avalondock, docking

In AvalonDock, is it possible to modify a `LayoutAnchorablePane`'s `CanClose` property dynamically at runtime? I would like to prevent/lock layout changes unless the user specifically desires to do so and turns it on.

I have tried the following approaches:

1. Binding: It is not possible to bind the property because it is not a `DependencyProperty` so something like this doesn't work: `<dock:LayoutAnchorable CanClose="{Binding CanClose}">`
2. `CanClose` property: Changing the `LayoutAnchorablePane`'s `CanClose` property in code-behind is not possible because the property is read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of [`LayoutAnchorablePane`](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Layout/LayoutAnchorablePane.cs#L67):

```
#region CanClose

public bool CanClose
{
  get
  {
    return Children.All( a => a.CanClose );
  }
}

#endregion
```

the `CanClose` property depends on all children of the pane, so one way to change the value of `CanClose` of a `LayoutAnchorablePane` is to set all its children's `CanClose` property to the value you want. Below is an example:

```
...
foreach(var child in pane.Children)
{
    child.CanClose = true; // or false.
}
...
```